# DropDown in ultrawebgrid is getting enabled after clicking on cell

Tags: infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I am binding the data from codebehind to the ultrawebgrid and the data is coming properly also, but the cell for the dropdown is coming as text field unless we click on it. Once the cell for the dropdown is clicked the dropdown is getting visible. I am allowing the cell to edit as well as to update it even then 'm facing this issue. please let me know how to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the column Type to ColumnType.DropDownList?

Comment: The behavior you are seeing sounds like expected behavior.  When you have a value list for the column or use the WebCombo as a drop down a single drop down is used and is dynamically positioned on the table cell when you enter edit mode.  What are you looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

create a dropdown and set it as the columns editor component. Try defining this earlier on;

add event `yourgrid_AfterInitializeLayout(blah blah )` handles `yourgrid.AfterInitializeLayout`

then set the `editorComponent` at the column level ;

`yourgrid.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns("yourColumn").EditorComponent = (your dropdown here)`

your grid should load with these as a drop down.  another place could be when the row is

activated.